# Failing hidden test about updating student using pickle module

Tags: python, pickle

I'm working on a problem as follow:
student_info.pkl contains a dumped list of students' information (already uploaded to the system). We create a copy of that file, named updated_info.pkl, to update new students.

Write a function to add the information of a student to the dumped list in updated_info.pkl. If the student ID in that information piece has already existed in the list, overwrite all of that student's information with the new one. If the student ID is missing, do nothing.

The content structure of the dumped list, for example:

```
student_info = [
  {
   'id': 20200000,
   'name': 'Nguyen Van A',
   'score': {
    'math': 7.8,
    'english': 8.9,
    'physics': 9.0,
   }
  },
  {
   'id': 20200001,
   'name': 'Le Van B',
   'score': {
    'math': 9.8,
    'english': 8.7,
    'physics': 7.6,
   }
  }
]
```

Test

```
new_student = {
        'id': 20200000,
        'name': 'Nguyen Van Anh',
        'score': {
            'math': 7.8,
            'english': 8.4,
            'physics': 8.0,
        }
    }
add_student_info(new_student)
```

Result

```
Before:
Number of student(s): 3
Name of student 0: Nguyen Van An
After:
Number of student(s): 3
Name of student 0: Nguyen Van Anh
```

Here is my code:

```
from shutil import copyfile
copyfile('student_info.pkl', 'updated_info.pkl')
#my code starts from here
def add_student_info(ne):
    with open('updated_info.pkl', 'rb') as f:
        a = pickle.load(f)
    for i in range(len(a)):
        if a[i]['id'] == ne['id']:
            a[i] = ne
            continue
    with open('updated_info.pkl', 'wb') as f:
        pickle.dump(a,f)
```

It performed well in the first test

Test

```
new_student = {
        'id': 20200000,
        'name': 'Nguyen Van Anh',
        'score': {
            'math': 7.8,
            'english': 8.4,
            'physics': 8.0,
        }
    }
add_student_info(new_student)
```

```
#Expected result
Before:
Number of student(s): 3
Name of student 0: Nguyen Van An
After:
Number of student(s): 3
Name of student 0: Nguyen Van Anh

#My result
Before:
Number of student(s): 3
Name of student 0: Nguyen Van An
After:
Number of student(s): 3
Name of student 0: Nguyen Van Anh
```

But when i submit it, the system said that i still failed a hidden test. Can someone tell me in what cases will my code faile or what i should do to improve this code ?

Comment: if the student name is different _add them_. There should be 4 students.

Comment: it only differ by the student id if the id of the new student has already exist in the pkl file, overwrite the student with that id in the file by the input student (even overwrite the name) so no new student is added here.